# Problem with python croniter with all asterisks

Tags: python, cron-task

I have made a script in python to perform FTP transfers that will run in crontab every minute. The script queries the mysql database and translates the cron language with the croniter library. If the current date and time match the programmed date, the ftp transaction will be performed.

It seems to work correctly except when the programming is cron is minutes and hours in asterisks. With the date it seems that there is no problem.

The crontotime function receives in the variable "programmed" the time and date programmed in cron language: "* * * * *" or "05 17 * * *" and translates it to date and time.

https://crontab.guru/ for help

Thanks.

```
 def crontotime(self,programada):
        crontask = croniter.croniter(programada)
        nextcrontask = crontask.get_next(datetime.datetime).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        return nextcrontask
```

Results: If there are no defined minutes and hours, an error appears

```
========================================================
Now:                    2019-03-25 16:56
Scheluded:   #* 16 * * *#   2019-03-25 16:00 
========================================================
Now:                    2019-03-25 16:56
Scheluded:  #56 16 * * *#   2019-03-25 16:56 
========================================================
Now:                        2019-03-25 17:05 
Scheluded   #* * * * *#     2019-03-25 16:06  ERROR
========================================================
Now:                    2019-03-25 17:05
Scheluded:  #05 17 * * *#   2019-03-25 17:05 
========================================================
```

Comment: What is printing `ERROR`? Where is the code that calls `crontotoime`?

Answer (score -1):

```
class Crontask(object):

def crontask(self,datoscron,ahora):
    for row_task in datoscron:
        programada = (' '.join(i for i in row_task[2:7]).strip())
        nuevatarea = Crontask().crontotime(programada)
        if nuevatarea == ahora:
            FTPtask().ftptask(row_task)
            LogTransfer().log_tareas(row_task)
        else:
            print("========================================================")
            print("///////////////// NO TRANSFER /////////////////////////")
            print("========================================================")
    return

def crontotime(self,programada):
    crontask = croniter.croniter(programada)
    nextcrontask = crontask.get_next(datetime.datetime).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    return nextcrontask
```

========================================================
Now:                        2019-03-26 11:57

## Scheluded:   #* * * * *#    2019-03-26 10:58

For example: scheluded is * * * * * and time is 2019-03-26 11:57, croniter return 2019-03-26 10:58 1 more minute, then task never runs.